# Angular changes not reflected when using asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, asset-pipeline

I have a Rails / Angular app, and I find when I update the Angular code, it is not immediately reflected in (development) application. I am accustomed to the Rails *reload to review* cycle, and have been having to restart the Rails app and log into & out of the application before Angular changes are reflected.

I assume this is an issue with the asset pipeline, as I am using it to deliver the Angular assets. I've had a look around on SO for a solution and have found some similar questions but no real solutions.

Does anyone know how to force the asset pipeline to minify and serve the changes to Angular js without requiring a server reload? To further complicate matters, most of the js is written in coffeescript.

Comment: Can you try resetting the timestamps of the assets? It might reload the assets

Comment: Do you mean with a touch command? The timestamps of the source files will be updated upon save... not sure about the compiled assets.

Comment: asset pipeline should not be the issue as you are working in development mode

Comment: Thanks @GhostRider you are right. So what process takes the Angular code written in coffeescript, compiles & minifies it and sends it to the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you precompile the assets manually, `rake assets:precompile` then you can avoid the restart. When you reload a server say in apache or nginx, the assets will not be compiled. You need to restart it to so that when the request to server is made, the assets will be compiled. When you make changes in any js,css files make sure you compile them manually.

Comment: Just a note: this method means I don't have to restart the Rails server, but I still have to log in / out of the application.

Answer (score 1):

### Possible Causes

Since you ran `rake assets:precompile` command recently, the script has created a folder `public/assets` and generated all the assets file the browser might ask for. So, when you make new changes in the js/CSS asset files, the requests from the browser are served from the `public/assets` directory.

### Solution

1. `rm -df public/assets`
2. `rake assets:clean`